# Identifying matching observations in dyadic data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-cleaning, data-transform

Hell everyone,

I am struggling with the following issue. Currently, I have a dataset looking like this:

```
    
   living_in     from           Year    stock
   Austria       Australia      2014       2513
   Austria       Australia      2013       2000
   Germany       Austria       2010       6000
   Australia     Austria       2014       3000
   Austria       Australia     1993        NA
```

Now I would like to identify all observations that fulfill the following criteria:

- Should be from same year
- Should contain the same country pairs in that year
- Should not contain NA

For instance, I want to find **all observations for combinations of two countries like Austria-Australia and Australia-Austria** within the **same year** that **contain values**. This is due to the fact that *some combinations in a given year in the dataset have only one value for stock not two*. I want to remove those.

What is the best way to proceed here? Many thanks in advance!

P.S. I have about 14 country pairs in my dataset that need this kind of identification

A helpful output might be something like this.

```
    
   living_in     from           Year    stock       dummy
   Austria       Australia      2014       2513       1
   Austria       Australia      2013       2000       0
   Germany       Austria       2010       6000        0
   Australia     Austria       2014       3000        1
   Austria       Australia     1993        NA         0
```

Comment: Thanks for you clarification @RonakShah. I added an expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each combination of country irrespective of their order (A-B is same as B-A) assign 1 to `dummy` column if for the same `Year` it has more than 1 row and `all` the `stock` values are non-`NA` or else assign 0.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(col1 = pmin(living_in, from), col2 = pmax(living_in, from), Year) %>%
  mutate(dummy = as.integer(n() > 1 && all(!is.na(stock)))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-col1, -col2)

#  living_in from       Year stock dummy
#  <chr>     <chr>     <int> <int> <int>
#1 Austria   Australia  2014  2513     1
#2 Austria   Australia  2013  2000     0
#3 Germany   Austria    2010  6000     0
#4 Australia Austria    2014  3000     1
#5 Austria   Australia  1993    NA     0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(living_in = c("Austria", "Austria", "Germany", 
"Australia", "Austria"), from = c("Australia", "Australia", "Austria", 
"Austria", "Australia"), Year = c(2014L, 2013L, 2010L, 2014L, 
1993L), stock = c(2513L, 2000L, 6000L, 3000L, NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```